# Two user inputs have to be divided by 5 so the program can finish

Tags: c#, console-application

Text of the task: A user needs to input numbers until the number that could be divided by 5 has been entered two times. Numbers that could be divided by 3 will reset the counter.

```
int a;
int b;
int counter = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
    a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
    b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    counter++;
    // - I am not sure how to set up counter to count a and b together
    // when the user enters a and b it counts as 1 not 2?

    if (a % 3 == 0 || b % 3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Counter is reseting");
        counter = 0;
    }

} while (a % 5 != 0 && b % 5 != 0);

Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

It takes me out of the loop when I enter once a number divided by 5, and it doesn't want to allow me to enter it twice. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand exactly what you're seeing. It would help if you could modify the prompts to show "Enter number a" and "Enter number b" then copy/paste the results of a session into the question, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: Like @DaisyShipton said it is very hard to understand what‘s happening.

Comment: You need to not only explain what you are seeing but exactly what you expect to see. I would ask whether you've actually debugged this code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code.  I'd wager not. You really need do that before posting a question here.  If you don't know how, learn now, starting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I modify explanation, thank you, I dont know much about debugging i will check out, thanks for the link

Comment: _I dont know much about debugging_ But should...

Comment: replies from below helped me, I added counter under a = parse.... and switched in while loop from && to || and works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood, you want to continue looping unless both values are dividable by 5. So your logic in the final *while* needs to be:

```
while( A_is_not_dividable_by_5 OR B_is_not_dividable_by_5 )
```

or

```
while( a % 5 != 0 || b % 5 != 0 )
```

Note the *or* rather than the *and*.

Comment: What about precedence of ***or*** vs. ***and*** operators in C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
counter++; 
Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
counter++;
```